# PHP - array_push wrong JSON format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to create a JSON array using php. Every time I post a new array the new one needs to append in front of the old array.

I have my code working however, it creates a strange format like `[{},[{},[{}]]]`.

The format I need for my JSON array to be is `[{},{},{}...]`

```
[{"Reg_Date":"28-07-2999","Name":"aaa","Surname":"aaa","VideoPath":"aaa","MyComment":"aaa", "ThumbPath":"aaa", "UserId":"aaa"},
{"Reg_Date":"18-07-2015","Name":"bbb","Surname":"bbb","bbb":"bbb","MyComment":"bbb", "ThumbPath":"bbb", "UserId":"bbb"}]
```

How can I create my array properly?

php:

```
$results = array ( array(
    "Reg_Date" => $Reg_Date, 
    "Name" => $NameUser, 
    "Surname" => $SurnameUser, 
    "VideoPath" => $VideoPath, 
    "MyComment" => $MyComment, 
    "ThumbPath" => $ThumbPath, 
    "UserId" => $UserId
    ));



$inp = file_get_contents('video_JSON_Test.json');
$arr = json_decode($inp);

array_push($results, $arr);


$fp_login = fopen('video_JSON_Test.json', w);
fwrite($fp_login, json_encode($results));
fclose($fp_login);

print_r($results);
echo $NameUser . $SurnameUser, $MyComment . "\n";
echo json_encode($arr)
```

;

Comment: When you do `array_push($results, $arr);`, you mean to add JSON data into the next index of `$results`, and not another Array?

Comment: Yes, sorry another index oh that array

Comment: Are there multiple arrays in `$arr`? Maybe you want `$results = array_merge($results, $arr);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
$arr = json_decode($inp);
array_push($results, $arr);
```

with:

```
$arr = json_decode($inp, true);
$results = array_merge($results, $arr);
```

Comment: i got the error :  array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: Strange, because in your example you show it as an array inserted in the main one. Could you `var_dump($arr)` and give the results?

Comment: it works just if the JSON file is already there with a list one index. If I delete the JSON file and start from 0 i get the error

Comment: Add true to your previous line: `json_decode($inp, true)` as suggested by others.

Answer (score 0):

You create double array (`array( array() )`) and assign its to `$results` variable. Next, you push this double array to earlier created array in similar construction. Look:

1 step: `array( array() )`, and we make `array_push()` on this array.

2 step: `array( array(), array( array() ) )`, because our double array land in array.

#### Solution?

1. Replace double array with single array and create empty container. So `$results = array();` and `$resultsContainer = array();`. Then you fill `$results` array with values and use `array_push($resultsContainer, $results)`.
2. Use `array_merge()` instead of `array_push()`. Details: [PHP: array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). But important is thing: you must have to two arrays. Look at doc for `json_decode()`: [PHP: json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). This function can return object instead of array. Use second argument `true` for associative array.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the double array, and in fact, you maintain the same principle with the suggested  `$resultsContainer`: it will become just as double as soon as it receives its first element.  It has to be, because the inner array represents in fact an object, but encoded as an associative array. The last point is indeed correct.